# Vue 3 - Broadcast Property Changes Down Tree

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

I have a Vue 3 app structured like this:

```
+---------------------+
| Component           |
| +-----------------+ |
| | Child Component | |
| +-----------------+ |
+---------------------+
```

The components are defined like this:

**my-component.vue**

```
<template>
  <button @click="addItem" />

  <child-component :items="items" />
</template>
<script>
  import Child from './my-child-component.vue';
  export default {
    components: { 'child-component' : Child },
    
    data() {
      items: {}   // NOTE: This is an object, not an array
    },

    methods: {
      addItem() {
        var count = Math.floor((Math.random() * 100) + 1);
        var name = 'item' + count;
        
        var children = [];
        for (var i=0; i<count; i++) {
          children.push(i+1);
        }

        this.items[name] = children;
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

**my-child-component.vue**

```
<template>
  <div>Details of the Items</div>
</template>
<script>
  export default {
    props: {
      items: {
        type: Object,
        default: {}
      }
    }        

    watch: {
      items() {
        console.log('the items have changed');
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

This code is dynamically adding properties to the `items` object. Unfortunately, the `child-component` is not seeing the `items` object change. In Vue 2, there was a `$vm.set` method to address this scenario. However, I'm not sure how to address this in Vue 3.

How can I dynamically update an object in a way that child components are aware of the change?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the watched property is a an object you should add the `deep:true` option :

```
    watch: {
      items: {
         handler(){
          console.log('the items have changed');
           },
        deep:true
       
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

When you make use of Vue3's `setup()` function, the properties are passed into it as the first argument, keeping their reactiveness. Here's a working example that triggers a watcher on each property change:

```js
const appConfig = {
  data() {
    return {
      items: {}
    }
  }
};

const app = Vue.createApp(appConfig);
app.component('ChildComponent', {
  props: {
    items: {
      type: Object,
      default: {}
    }
  },
  template: 'items: {{items}}',
  setup(props) {
    Vue.watch(props.items, () => {
      console.log("items changed");
    });

    return {
      items: props.items
    }
  }
});

app.mount('#app');
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3.0.11/dist/vue.global.prod.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <button @click="items[Object.keys(items).length] = true">add</button>
  <p>
    <child-component :items="items" />
  </p>
</div>
```